# Enter a file name and read the array

Tags: arrays, fortran, filenames

I searched it on the forum but couldn't find an answer to my question. If I missed something, I am sorry. So, here is my question:

I have a code as below:

```
program averagepro
implicit none
real,allocatable,dimension(:) :: a
real :: realfunctionaverage
integer :: i,n
character :: response,filename
print*,'How many numbers would you like to enter?'
read*,n
allocate(a(n))
print*,'Would you like to enter numbers by reading from a file or from the keyboard?'
print*,'Press "F" to enter using a file or "K" to enter from keyboard.'
read*,response
if  (response=='F' .or. response=='f') then
    print*,'Please enter the name correctly, as well as regarding capital letters and file extension: '
    read*,filename
!   print*, filename
!   open(12,file='array.txt')
    open(12,file='filename')
    do  i=1,n
        read(12,*) a(i)
    enddo
elseif  (response=='K'.or. response=='k') then
    print*,'Please enter the numbers, one at each time: '
    do  i=1,n
        read*,a(i)
    enddo
else
    stop
endif
write(*,10) ' The average of the numbers entered are: ',realfunctionaverage(n,a)
10  format(a,2f10.3)
deallocate(a)
end program averagepro 
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function realfunctionaverage(m,list)
implicit none
integer :: m,i
real,dimension(m) :: list
real :: realfunctionaverage,ans
ans=0
do  i=1,m
    ans=ans+list(i)
enddo
realfunctionaverage=ans/m
end function realfunctionaverage
```

I am having problem while I try to enter the file name from the keyboard. When the program asks for the file name, I define it as "array.txt" or "array"; but it gives an error and stops running. How should I do it? By the way, when I disable somelines and directly write the filename which is "array.txt", program works properly.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to specify what error does exactly occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to open the file called "filename" no matter what the user enters.  This line:

```
open(12,file='filename')
```

should be:

```
open(12,file=filename)
```

With quotes it is the string literal "filename", without quotes it is the contents of the variable named `filename`.

You will also need to declare the variable `filename` with some length to accommodate a filename.

```
character(len=256) :: filename
```

should be adequate for most use cases.  Without a `len`, the character variable can only hold a single character.